# How can I recode to enable for 2 and 3?

Tags: c++

How do i make it say 2 and 3 are prime numbers?

checks for prime numbers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double number;
char a;
    do {
    cout << "Enter an integer greater than 1 to check if it is a prime number: ";
    cin >> number;
    for (int x=2; x<=sqrt(number); x++) {

        int number;
        if (number%x==0) {
            cout << "The number " << number << " is NOT a prime number." << endl;
            break;
        }
        else {cout << "The number " << number << " is a prime number." << endl;
        break;}
    }
    cout << "Do you want to enter another number? (y or n): ";
    cin >> a;
}while (a=='y'||a=='Y');
    cout << "Exiting program ..." << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

when i attempt to run for 2 and 3 it just skips to do you want to enter another number
it works for all n>3, i must use sqrt(n) and setflags(i was to add them later)

all help will be appreciated

Comment: 2 and 3 result in no output from either part of the `if` `else`?

Comment: Logic is wrong for this, variable declaration and scope is not clear. I would recomend to learn basics of scope and datatype

Comment: `sqrt(2)` and `sqrt(3)` both give a result that is less than `2`.   So the condition of the `for` loop will be true, and the loop body will never be executed.   That's what you need to fix.    Also, printing the indication of "prime" or "NOT prime" should happen after the loop.  As your code is at present, entering a large prime value will result in multiple lines of output saying it is prime, and entering a composite (non-prime) value will give multiple lines of output, some saying it is prime and some saying it isn't.

Answer (score 2):

> How do i make it say 2 and 3 are prime numbers?

Add an explicit test for them.

It becomes easier if you add a function `is_prime`.

Also, note that whe you are trying to determine whether a number is a prime number, the number is an integral number, not a floating point number.

Here's a revised version of your `main` function.

```
bool is_prime(int number)
{
   if ( number == 2 || number == 3)
   {
      return true;
   }

   for (int x=2; x*x <= number; x++)
   {
      if (number%x==0)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}

int main()
{
   int number;
   char a;
   do {
      cout << "Enter an integer greater than 1 to check if it is a prime number: ";
      cin >> number;
      if ( is_prime(number) )
      {
         cout << "The number " << number << " is a prime number." << endl;
      }
      else
      {
         cout << "The number " << number << " is NOT a prime number." << endl;
      }

      cout << "Do you want to enter another number? (y or n): ";
      cin >> a;
   }while (a=='y'||a=='Y');

   cout << "Exiting program ..." << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The square root of 2 and 3 are less than 2. `x=2`, so `x` will always be greater than sqrt(number) where number = 2 or 3. Thus, the condition use for the loop (`x<=sqrt(number)`) will always be false for 2 and 3.

```
\|2 = 1.41
\|3 = 1.73

 Approximately, of course.
```

**Edit:** I realized you asked for a way to recode it too, so I will give it a shot.

```
bool isPrime(int n) {
    // var to hold whether we are a prime
    bool result = true;
    for(int i = 2;i<n/(2+1);i++) {
        // if we are evenly divisible by i, we're not a prime.
        if(n%i == 0) {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    // return what we found
    return result;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
if (!isPrime(number)) {
    cout << "The number " << number << " is NOT a prime number." << endl;
} else { 
    cout << "The number " << number << " is a prime number." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please check in question variable `number` is again defined in inner scope which will not going to work

Comment: This can be comment not an answer!

Comment: Yeah. That's another problem. However, I don't think that will cause the problem he is describing. He is wondering why it skips 2 and 3, which is probably why it's doing that.

Comment: Yeah it is different thing, in for loop comparing int with double. I think datatype need to understand properly for new commer

Comment: have you check mine version, just to understand basic for new commer I have posted that answer

Answer (score -1):

First of all your logic to check prime number is WRONG!!

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main()  
{  
  int n, i, m=0, flag=0;
  char a;
  do{


  cout << "Enter the Number to check Prime: ";  
  cin >> n;  
  m=n/2;  
  for(i = 2; i <= m; i++)  
  {  
      if(n % i == 0)  
      {  
          cout<<"Number is not Prime."<<endl;  
          flag=1;  
          break;  
      }  
  }  
  if (flag==0)  
      cout << "Number is Prime."<<endl;  
    cout << "Do you want to enter another number? (y or n): ";
    cin >> a;  
  }while(a=='y'||a=='Y');

  return 0;  
}
```

This is the correct way to check prime number!!!
I hope you will understand from this.